# Online Prayer Time in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, xml

I need to get online prayers time for where ever city user is sitting and accessing application. and after that i need to customize it(getting prayer values and implement)

Can you please help me with examples and links how to access and implement it . 
Thanks

Comment: Isbah you can use any website which offer feeds or service to give prayer times. See http://www.islamicfinder.org/prayer_search.php for example. Also https://github.com/meltuhamy/masjid-times/wiki/Prayer-Times-Web-Service

Comment: I have gont through this website but what since i am new in sharepoint , i dont know how to implement it , how to call api's, can u please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isbah you can use any website which offer feeds or service to give prayer times. See islamicfinder.org/prayer_search.php for example.

Also github.com/meltuhamy/masjid-times/wiki/Prayer-Times-Web-Service